# I have 2 tables how to get all the fields from table b when there is a join

Tags: sql, join

Table A has a field called chRegionCode that is the key for Table B - whats the SQL for getting all the fileds for the record in Table B with the key chRegionCode from table A. But to read Table A i use this key chClientCode.

So I need the SQL to give me Table B when I have the key to Table A chClientCode - knowing that Table A contains the key to Table B (chRegionCode)

p.s I'm newish to sql

Thanks Joe

Comment: This is very hard to understand. Please make it clear when you are talking about a value in a field of rows returned and when you are just talking about a field being in table. Please don't use "key", use either primary key or foreign key; explain exactly what each primary key is and what each foreign key is and what it references where. If "have the key" means you have a value, give it a name or number to be used in a query. "But to read Table A i use this key chClientCode." is unintelligible.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * from TableB b where exists(select 'x' from TableA a where chClientCode=? and chRegionCode=b.chRegionCode)
```

Or if you want to select from both tables then use this :-

```
select * from TableA a , TableB b
where a.chRegionCode=b.chRegionCode
and a.chClientCode=?
```

substitute your chclientcode in place of '?' .

Answer (score 0):

Like this

SELECT (specify the column names from table B for which you want to retrieve as a comma-seperated list)

FROM table A

JOIN table B

ON tableA.chRegionCode = tableB.chRegionCode

WHERE chClientCode = (the value for the record you want to retrieve from table A)

Note the "." character, if 2 tables are joined using a certain column name (foreign keys) in this case "chRegionCode", you have to use the "." like that or you will get an exception

Comment: You can use both ON and WHERE, he wants to retrieve a record from table A with a chClientCode then retrieve the data from table B identified by the key chRegionCode, overall his question is really confusing

Answer (score 0):

> But to read Table A i use this key chClientCode.

If you mean that A just happens to have primary key chClientCode but you want the rows in B that have the same chRegionCode value as some row in A then:

```
select b.*
from a join b
on a.chRegionCode=b.chRegionCode
```

If you mean that you want the rows in B that have the same chRegionCode value as some row in A that has chClientCode=K then:

```
select b.*
from a join b
on a.chRegionCode=b.chRegionCode
where chClientCode=K
```